# Magento Error while loading the site

Tags: magento, exception

In magento am getting this error:

> There has been an error processing your request Exception printing is
> disabled by default for security reasons. Error log record number:
> 506600012505
>
> Magento is a trademark of Magento Inc. Copyright © 2012 Magento Inc.

Error log record number varies. I changed the line in `/lib/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php` and created a tmp folder but still my site doesn't work.

The errors are :

```
Trace:
#0 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(96): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(313): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(459): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(‘SET NAMES utf8′, Array)
#4 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query(‘SET NAMES utf8′, Array)
#5 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(169): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(‘SET NAMES utf8′)
#6 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection(‘pdo_mysql’, Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection(‘core_write’)
#8 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection(‘write’)
#9 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(360): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->getReadConnection()
#12 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#13 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance(‘core_resource/w…’, Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#14 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/Mage.php(490): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance(‘core/website_co…’, Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#15 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(208): Mage::getResourceModel(‘core/website_co…’, Object(Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Website))
#16 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getResourceCollection()
#17 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(608): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->getCollection()
#18 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(466): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initStores()
#19 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(349): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initCurrentStore(”, ‘store’)
#20 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#21 /data/www/magento/release-20140930/www/index.php(91): Mage::run(”, ‘store’)
#22 {main}
```

Could you please provide me a solution

Answer (score 0):

Check `var/log/system.log` and `var/log/exception.log`.

Open the file (if remote ssh terminal, you can use `pico system.log`. Entering `Ctrl+W+V` should get you to the bottom of the file, showing the latest error.)

These can tell you more specifically what is causing the error.